# Integrity constraint violation occurs when uploading file in webform

Tags: webforms

I watched it happens when trying to upload a specific file with the name "קורות חיים.docx", it happens to any visitor how try to upload a resume file with the exact same name in a webform.

this is the error message:

An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally.
Debugging information follows.
Path: /file/ajax/submitted/cvfile/form-HbzcUMPLqQmPttwZ8m5o_NPx-9dhMVALHpji_ckOO3g
StatusText: n/a
ResponseText: 
Username *
Enter your ידידים למען הנוער והחברה username.
Password *
Enter the password that accompanies your username.
Error               The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error message
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'public://webform/cv/קורות חיים_158.docx' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (uid, filename, uri, filemime, filesize, status, timestamp, type) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array
(
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 0
[:db_insert_placeholder_1] => קורות חיים.docx
[:db_insert_placeholder_2] => public://webform/cv/קורות חיים_158.docx
[:db_insert_placeholder_3] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
[:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 12968
[:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 0
[:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1431424601
[:db_insert_placeholder_7] => default
)
in drupal_write_record() (line 7239 of /home/yedidimorg/public_html/includes/common.inc).

ReadyState: undefined